# Is $\nabla F(x, y, z)\cdot \hat y$ related to the derivative of $F$ in the direction of $y$-axis?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function. I was wondering what is exactly
$$\nabla F(x, y, z)\cdot \hat y,$$

where "$\cdot$" denotes the dot product and $\hat{y}$ is the unit vector in the direction of $y$-axis.

Intuitively, I would say that it is something related to the derivative of $F$ along the direction of $y$, but I am not sure about that.

Could someone please help to understand that? Any example would be really appreciated, too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply,
$$\nabla F\cdot \boldsymbol e_y=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \\ =0\cdot \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+1\cdot \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}+0\cdot\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \\ =\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$$

Comment: K.defaoite, I had that suspicion.. Thank you!

Comment: While the answer is correct, I think it is worth mentioning that what you do is called a directional derivative. In this case a directional derivative along the y axis.